# Can i use external jdk path inside websphere

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, hudson

I am getting error bad version java

because hudson builder use java 1.7 where webspare use default 1.6.

how can i change my 1.7 java path inside websphere.

Comment: By the way, which version of Websphere are you using? It might not be compatible with 1.7

Comment: Adding to Mukul's comment, the version of WebSphere and the edition of WebSphere are needed before some answers can be provided. The response from Mukul below has assumes WAS CE (based on Geronimo) while you might be talking about the regular WAS editions.

Comment: websphere 8.5 version

Answer (score 1):

The following steps should do

1. Stop the server.
2. In the `WASCE_INSTALLED_DIR\bin\setenv.bat` file, set the `WASCE_JAVA_HOME` variable to point to the JRE you wish to use. You should check with the WebSphere Application Server CE documentation on supported versions and vendors before making this change.
3. Start the server.

Note that the version of the JRE listed in the console window now references the new Java version.